# Shrink Partition Windows 10 install xubuntu missing disk on installation

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, xubuntu, ssd

I've recently acquired a new laptop a Asus Rog g752vy. I am a linux user, but I decided to keep windows just in case if one day I want to play a game or use some of the adobe products.

The laptop has 2 hd: ssd 256gb (Windows 10 is installed here) and hd 1024gb.

On Windows 10, I've created a Shrink partition on the ssd, basically without formatting you can create a partition.

Then, I put xubuntu on a usb stick and I tried to install, but at the time of partitioning the disk, I only see the 1024gb and not the ssd. The ssd was formatted as ntfs. could that be the issue?

I read in some places that I had to upgrade the bios, I did that.
I read in some other places that the secure boot should be disabled, I did that too.
I had also disabled fastboot from Power settings.

But I am not able to see that disk, any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like you didn't disabled Windows fastboot, did you?

Comment: I forgot to mention, but that was disabled too.

Comment: I don't know what a "shrink" partition is. Please explain. Is your goal to install Xubuntu on the 256G SSD? And why Xubuntu vs Ubuntu?

Comment: Shrink partition is a new thing in windows 10, basically you can resize a partition that already have windows installed, without having to format. I have solved my issue, it was that I needed to change in bios the Sata from RAID to AHCI

Comment: @peterpeterson I was about to suggest just that because the problem with the RAID mode is known. Glad you solved it but now you need to fix or reinstall Windows 10. PS - The disk manager and the possibility to resize partitions is definitely not a "new thing", it's been there since XP at least.